# Calculate the probability of seeing a landmark when starting at a given point and walking straight in a random direction

Tags: code-golf, probability-theory

**Input** 5 integers: Landmark `X` & `Y`, Starting Point `X` & `Y`, and View Distance Radius `D`

**Output** 1 double: % chance of coming within `D` of Landmark (`X`,`Y`) ("seeing") when walking straight in a random direction from Starting Point (`X`,`Y`).

Assume that "random direction" shall be a direction uniform on [0,2π], the land is flat, and of course the 'hiker' never turns after he begins moving.

**Example:** If landmark is at (10,10), starting point is (5,5), and view distance is 20 then the output would be 100% as no matter which direction you walk the landmark will be immediately visible.

Comment: This kinda lost its appeal since you already linked to the solution.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I hadn't considered that since it is hardly implemented as code... but I suppose I can remove it if people also want to solve the math.

Comment: @ioSamurai just wanted to let you know that people can still see the math if they choose to look at the [revisions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/35030/revisions) - although I don't see any problem with leaving the math there.. people would be able to copy the math from the first answer, and would be challenged with optimizing the space anyways...

Comment: @user2813274 Yeah I didn't think showing the math was an issue anyways because it was really about the coding.

Comment: If you want to make this challenging/interesting, i suggest you ban trigonometric functions. Accuracy of probability should also be specified (I suggest to the nearest 1%, given that probability can be from 0 to 100%.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CJam *-41* *-40* *-39* *-38/35* **31/26**

This seems to work. It is my first attempt at CJam and/or codegolf.  Run the code at http://cjam.aditsu.net/. In the section called input just place the variables as integers delimited with spaces in the input block in this order: distance D, landmark x, starting x, landmark y, starting y  (for example 20 10 5 10 5).  I had posted a previous one based on a misunderstanding of the equation that has been resolved.  I also had been returning answers as probability ratios rather than percentages.  **Note: the second code has only 31 characters** but combines alot from another user's CJam code.

```
ri{riri- 2#}:U;UU+.5#/mSP/:A.5<A1?e2

r{~riri-_*}_~+mq/mSP/:A.5<A1?e2
```

Accuratish one without arcsine being directly called (44 characters):

```
ririri- 2#riri- 2#+ .5#/:A1<AA3#6/+P/1?100*
```

Even more accurate (52 characters):

```
ririri- 2#riri- 2#+ .5#/:A1<AA3#6/+A5#40/3*+P/1?100
```

Update:

The absolute best I've written is 26 characters.  I've still learned alot by watching professorfish's attempts but the crux is mine.  I assumes (potentially incorrectly) that if you can see the landmark if it is closer (not closer than or equal to) your sight radius.

```
1r{~riri-_*}_~+mq/mSP/e<e2
```

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <s>65</s> 63

```hs
import Data.Complex
(s,l)%d=100*min(asin(d/magnitude(s-l))/pi)1
```

Use like `(xstart:+ystart, xlandmark:+ylandmark) % distance`.  Gives result in percent.  Why is it so expensive to load modules in Haskell?!?

Note that there is no if/then/else, pattern matching, etc. in this code, `min` does the magic.

Comment: I didn't expect Haskell to do so well here, nor the Spanish Inquisition. :D

Comment: what is the undocumented feature, if i may ask?

Comment: is it the fixity of `\`min\``?

Comment: @proud haskeller: the way `min` deals with `NaN`.  Since `NaN` compares to a non-`NaN` to `False`, the exact implementation of `min` is relevant (whether or not it uses the inverse of a result of a comparison).  As far as I can tell, this behaviour is not specified anywhere, but I'd be glad to be proven wrong.

Comment: when you write NaN, you mean undefined? or is there some other NaN I'm not aware about?

Comment: oh you're talking about 0/0? i see.

Comment: We commented simultaneously, so yes, it's the fixity, and it's in the hs98 report, but you have to think about it when you read it.  By `NaN` I mean the result of a computation that doesn't have a result representable in the relevant data type, such as `asin x` with `abs x > 1` in this case.  `undefined` is something very different.

Comment: actually, i'd say that is an undocumented feature in the instance of `Compare (Complex a)`, but yes.

Comment: i used to think NaN is a value that is represented by the data type, but has no meaning, something like `3%0` in Data.Ratio . but i guess it could be useful returning NaN instead of undefined so that something valuable could be done with the result even when an error occurred.

Comment: what happens if you input 0,0(start) 0,5(landmark) 5(viewing distance)?  I think this code is effectively identical to my 26 character one.

Comment: @kaine: 50, just like it should.

Comment: Im not sure whether it should or shouldn't. Can you see it if $ r <d $ or $ r <=d $? I prefer it this , however, as that is the shorter of my answers.

Comment: +1, importing is really expensive when golfing in Haskell. To use `sort (compare 'on' key)`, one need to do `import Data.List; import Data.Function;`...

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <del>44 40 38</del> 37

First CJam script! Uses the method [on the Math.SE answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876462/calculation-for-the-chance-of-finding-something-a-given-distance-from-a-starting/876580#876580).

Supports non-integer inputs as well, at no extra character cost.

```
rd{rdrd-_*}:U~U+mq/_1<{mSP/}{;1}?100*
```

[Interpreter at cjam.aditsu.net](http://cjam.aditsu.net).

### Order of inputs

The inputs are given in this order, on STDIN, separated by spaces:

1. View Distance Radius
2. Landmark X
3. Starting Point X
4. Landmark Y
5. Starting Point Y

Comment: Why not use P instead of 3.14? P starts off defined as pi  This will give you the same length as mine.

Comment: @kaine Fortunately I've thought of another saving, I'm now beating you by one character

Comment: How is that fortunate?

Comment: There is, what I believe, to be a mistake in this.  If you start exactly as far as you can see away, you get 50% on yours 100% on mine. Easy change. An it is debatable which is correct.

Comment: ri{riri-_*}:U;UU+mq/_1>{;1}{mSP/}?100* you are welcome dammit

Comment: I'm going to stop becaue the more I try to trim both yours and mine, the closer to each other they get!

Comment: @kaine fixed the bug, same char count

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell — <del>72 70 69</del> 68

I think this satisfies the question, but if not please leave a comment and I'll do my best to fix it:

```haskell
w s y l z d|r<d=100|0<1=asin(d/r)/pi*100where r=sqrt$(l-s)^2+(z-y)^2
```

Comment: you can replace `True` with `0<1`, and use $ in the definition of r.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that `$` opportunity.

Comment: You could also squish `where` up against `100`.

Comment: It breaks vim's syntax highlighting (why I didn't delete the space in the first place), but it does indeed compile.

Comment: Also, `asinh` should really be `asin`. The character reduction is a bonus!

Comment: `asin` kept returning `NaN`

Comment: They're not the same. `asin(1)`=PI/2=1.57 `asinh(1)`=0.88. If `asin` is giving `NaN` it's because you're giving it an argument outside the range -1 to 1, which doesn't make sense according to the definition of `sin`.

Comment: @steveverrill Sorry about that, I tried again and I think when I was getting `NaN` I was using invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 73

```py
from math import*
f=lambda l,s,d:(abs(l-s)<=d or asin(d/abs(l-s))/pi)*100
```

`l` is a complex number (e.g. `5 + 5j`) describing the landmark position, `s` describes the start position and `d` is the view distance, for the example from the question call `f` as follows: `f(5 + 5j, 10 + 10j, 20)`

Comment: I guess you are missing a bracket ```(```.

Comment: Now you are missing two brackets ```(```...```)```. ;) Otherwise you might return ```True``` rather than ```100``` in case the landmark is closer than the distance ```d```.

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean...